# Neo4j nested conditional statement

Tags: neo4j

I'm very new with this technology. I'm trying to prevent that a value goes below 0 and above 1. And if the relationship does not exists to set the value

I have tried this:

```
MATCH (t:Transmission{ identifier: '12345678' })-[r:EPISODE_OF]-(n:Series{ 
title: 'Buffy the Vampire Slayer' })
SET 
r.quality = CASE WHEN r.quality IS NULL THEN 0.3
ELSE CASE WHEN r.quality + 0.3 > 1 THEN 1 
ELSE CASE WHEN r.quality + 0.3 < 0 THEN 0 
ELSE r.quality = r.quality + 0.3 END
return t;
```

Any ideas? I recieve an error that I don't understand.

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'r': expected 
whitespace, comment, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, 
CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', '~', "<>", "!=", '<', 
'>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR or END (line 7, column 1 (offset: 284))
"return t"
^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to repeat the `CASE` multiple times. This should do the trick:

```
MATCH (t:Transmission{ identifier: '12345678' })-[r:EPISODE_OF]-(n:Series{ title: 'Buffy the Vampire Slayer' })
SET r.quality = CASE WHEN r.quality IS NULL THEN 0.3
  WHEN r.quality + 0.3 > 1 THEN 1 
  WHEN r.quality + 0.3 < 0 THEN 0 
  ELSE r.quality + 0.3 END
RETURN t
```